# AngularJS: Difference between Custom directive type Attribute and type Element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Assuming that a Custom Directive:

- define a custom tag or attribute that is expanded or replaced
- can include Controller logic, if needed

and that the Directive can be of type Element

```
<my-customdirective></my-customdirective>
```

or of type Attribute

```
<h4 my-customdirective></h4>
```

my question is WHEN and WHY I decide to use one rather than another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoted from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> **When should I use an attribute versus an element?** Use an element when
>   you are creating a component that is in control of the template. The
>   common case for this is when you are creating a Domain-Specific
>   Language for parts of your template. Use an attribute when you are
>   decorating an existing element with new functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Some points to consider:

- Most of the time attributes is the best/most convenient option (it's not the default by chance).
- Anything you can do with element-bound directives, you can do with attribute-bound as well.
- Element-bound directives can be more descriptive/readable at times.
- If you want your code to pass certain types of validation, you should use attributes.
- Since you want to support IE8, keep in mind that custom tags have an extra overhead (more info), which hurts maintainability.

[For More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903029/angular-directives-element-or-attribute/23923561#23923561)