# Using custom tags or HTML tags with Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am starting with angular and I often see two different approaches of using a module:

```
<input autocomplete options="..."/>
```

And:

```
<autocomplete options="..."/>
```

I think the first one is a better options since it uses the native HTML tags.

Is there a reason, or advantage of using the second approach?

In my opinion the HTML code becomes quite strange ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular directives - element or attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903029/angular-directives-element-or-attribute)

Comment: It's one of the Angular's strengths - to make the `HTML` "readable". You can actually see what the DOM element's specific function is. In my opinion choosing between element or attribute is about what it's for, if it's a `div` you may want it to be an element, but for `input` then perhaps attribute is most transparent.