# Angular JS : When should you use an attribute versus an element?

Tags: angularjs

As an angularjs developer i want to know when i should use attribute versus an element

AS per my understanding and development knowledge Use an element when you are creating a component that is in control of the template. Use an attribute when you are decorating an existing element with new functionality.

But i am not sure ... please suggest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular directives - element or attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903029/angular-directives-element-or-attribute)

Comment: this question can be reopened as I know the fact why to use an element when the directive is supposed to do any modification in DOM. Their preference is not opinion based. In can answer this question

Answer (score 1):

[Angular directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

[Original answer by ckruszynsky:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23923561/3338750)

> The angular guidance says that you should use the "element"
>   restriction whenever the directive has full control over it's template
>   meaning it has a template that it is rendering out, etc.
>
> For attributes, they suggest to use these only when you are adding
>   "behavior" to an existing element or decorating an existing element.
>
> For example, think of the ng-click directive, this is used a attribute
>   not as a element because the click directive is just adding the click
>   behavior to some element.
>
> Another example would be the ng-repeat directive, it is also used as
>   an attribute not as a element because it is going to repeat the
>   element in which it is being used in.
>
> Now, this guidance is from the angular documentation; however, I don't
>   know necessarily that element vs. attribute is going to give you a
>   "better" approach it's more of a convention.
>
> Now if you have to support older browsers, then you may want to
>   consider using either the comment or class directives.
>
> My personal preference is to just use the attribute restriction;
>   mainly because people that are new to angular get overwhelmed at first
>   when they see the restrict and it's variations of the options that can
>   be used.

Comment: If you're answer is almost entirely quoting from an answer to another question, then the question you're answering is likely a duplicate of that other question. Thus, rather than answering, it would be better to flag the question to be closed as a duplicate of the other question.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite opinion based, personnaly i use only attributes but i'm probably not the one to follow

However i can address some points following how HTML is designed :

- element fits for a component (like an input, table).
- attributes fits for options that influence the behaviour of your component (like type="text"). But they can be used as components too, as long you don't use two of them in the same element.